# File picker dialogs do not remember settings when Firefox is running in firejail

Tags: firefox, gtk, firejail, file-chooser

When Firefox is running in Firejail with the provided default config, the Gtk file picker dialogs do not remember sort order even when Firefox was not restarted between opening two dialogs.

I tried copying the firejail profile and allowing access to `.config/gtk-2.0` and `.config/gtk-3.0` but it doesn't seem to work. It also seems that the `gtk-2.0` folder has a `gtkfilechooser.ini` with these settings, while the `gtk-3.0` folder does not. I wonder where it stores this configuration.

What files do I need to whitelist, so the Gtk filechooser dialogs can access (and possibly store) their settings?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox / Gtk 3.0 seem to use dconf, which cannot be accessed with the default firejail profiles and probably shouldn't be whitelisted for security reasons. Here is a [related bug](https://github.com/celluloid-player/celluloid/issues/683) from another project.

A workaround is to set `GSETTINGS_BACKEND=keyfile`. It probably depends on other whitelisted paths if they settings file is persisted between runs, but as long as Firefox is running, subsequent file dialogs remember the settings.